# duplicate jframes appear in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, jframe

I am transferring data from a jtable in frame1 to another jtable in frame2.
the problem is, every time i select a row from my first table and press the button(to transfer it to the other table) another frame pops up and the data is fed in the first row. I want all the selected data to be in the same table.

I know ive written something wrong in my code but i doesnt know a right solution to it ! here is my code

```
 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int row = jTable2.getSelectedRow();        
    String a1=jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
    String a2=jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).toString();
    String a3=jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(row, 21).toString();
    String a4=jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(row, 5).toString();
    String a5=jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(row, 22).toString();
     NewJFrame2 fr2 = new NewJFrame2();
     fr2.gencode(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
        //this.dispose();
        fr2.setVisible(true);
}
```

and this in another frame

```
public NewJFrame2() {
    initComponents();
}
        int i=0;
        public void gencode(String a1, String a2, String a3, String a4, String a5){
            System.out.print(i);
            i++;
        jTable1.setValueAt(a1, i, 0);
        jTable1.setValueAt(a2, i, 1);
        jTable1.setValueAt(a3, i, 2);
        jTable1.setValueAt(a4, i, 3);
        jTable1.setValueAt(a5, i, 4);

   }
```

Comment: You creating a new instance of `JFrame`, as `NewJFrame2 fr2 = new NewJFrame2();`, in the `actionPerformed` method, so it is quite obvious, that a new `JFrame` is bound to come. Instead use the same reference, and do not use `new NewJFrame2 ()` in `actionPerformed (...)` method. Simply make `NewJFrame2 fr2` instance variable, instead of making it a local variable, and initialize it only once somewhere.

Comment: Every time you are creating a new NewJFrame2 fr2 = new NewJFrame2(); object that's why its creating. Try to create it once in it in the class as its data member and use it jButton3ActionPerformed

Comment: @nIcEcOw yes i know that. How do i correct it ?

Comment: @AnmolKhanna do you want jtable 2 appear in new frame or same frame ??

Comment: @FastSnail i am feeding rows from jtable2 to jtable1 in a different frame

Comment: Ohh problem solved. I was declaring it locally.
i declared my frame2 globally and its working perfectly fine now.
just a cut paste of a line.
Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is you are creating new frame inside button click event

```
 NewJFrame2 fr2 = new NewJFrame2(); //here is the problem
```

in your frame one declare a instance variable frame2

```
class One{
  NewJFrame2 fr2;
}
```

and initialize it when you need but only one time
and in the action method use

```
  if(fr2==null){
      fr2=new  NewJFrame2(); //initialize if it's null
  }
  fr2.gencode(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NewJFrame2 fr2=null; //class level variable
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int row = jTable2.getSelectedRow();        
        String a1=jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
        String a2=jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).toString();
        String a3=jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(row, 21).toString();
        String a4=jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(row, 5).toString();
        String a5=jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(row, 22).toString();
        //create instance when not initiated
        if(fr1==null){
            fr2 = new NewJFrame2();
        }
         fr2.gencode(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
            //this.dispose();
            fr2.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Make fr2 as class level variable and create instance when not initiated